# How to use android custom component dynamic attr

Tags: android, dynamic, components, attr

I made a custom component, piechart and in the `GraphicalView.class`, I set this in this class
`Value=attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "GO", 80);`

So now, I can add a component by put these code in xml

`<view`

`class="org.piechart.GraphicalView"`

`android:id="@+id/piechart"`

`GO="48"`
`/>`

but in this situation, i have to dynamic modify the piechart value in Activity,
i hope i can use

`View view1= (View)findViewById(R.id.piechart); view1.set ????`

but i have no idea how to modify the value

i have to use xml to put a component to layout,and i have to dynamic modify the the component value